# Setting up an internal NLB with private static IP pointed to an ALB in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, architecture

Here is our current setup.

NOT WORKING
Route53 -> NLB (internal, private ip) -> ALB -> Lambda

WORKING
Route53 -> NLB (public, elastic ip) -> ALB -> Lambda

All are in a VPC. I have set security groups to allow everything for now.

My issue is I cannot access the lambda with the setup above using internal nlb with private ip.

Can anyone enlighten me on this?

Thank you

Comment: I wonder, did you catch where in the chain does it fail? I assume its this "NLB (internal, private ip) -> ALB" right?

Comment: Ok. I think I figured this out. If you are using private IP, then your computer should be in the same "network" as the private NLB. This can only happen if you setup your VPN to connect to your AWS Virtual Private Gateway. My internal NLB is working if ping from an EC2 inside the same VPC.